# jQuery plugin MixItUp not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I followed the instructions in this tutorial to get MixItUp to work:
https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/get-started/

I'm just trying to get the filtering working, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LY2Nj/

```
<div class="controls">
  <button class="filter" data-filter="all" type="button">
    Show all
  </button> 
  <button class="filter" data-filter=".yellow" type="button">
    Yellow
  </button>
  <button class="filter" data-filter=".green" type="button">
    Green
  </button>
  <button class="filter" data-filter=".red" type="button">
    Red
  </button>    
</div>

<div id="color-container">
  <div class="mix yellow">
      <p>Yellow</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mix green">
      <p>Green</p>
  </div>    
  <div class="mix red">
      <p>Red</p>
  </div>    
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Start mixitup
  $('#color-container').mixItUp();
});
```

css

```
#color-container .mix{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I had a problem with the Mixitup filter: my elements were reappearring when the filter was applied. Forgot the .mix CSS class with the display:none propertie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get your fiddle to work by adding the external MixItUp core script:

http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mixitup/latest/jquery.mixitup.min.js